# SQL Show Duplicate Entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a SQL code that is pulling information from a database.  Here's the code:

```
$info = "SELECT field_5, record_meta_keywords
FROM cms_custom_database_1
WHERE field_5 > ''
GROUP BY field_5
ORDER BY field_5
DESC LIMIT 10";
```

The problem is that field_5 has duplicate entries.  For example, there are two 868's in that field, but the output is only showing one and not the other.  How can I alter this to display all entries and not just one of each number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use group by without aggregation function

```
SELECT field_5, record_meta_keywords
FROM cms_custom_database_1
WHERE field_5 > ''
ORDER BY field_5
DESC LIMIT 10
```

if you want distinct value then use distinct

the use of `group by` without aggregation function is deprecated  in SQL,   not allowed (by default) in most recent version of mysql, and produce unpredictable result with other versions (<5.7)

In your case if you want see all the result then just remove `order by`

Answer (score 2):

You are explicitly stating -- via the `group by` -- that you want only one row in the result set for each value of `field_5`.

That leaves you with two options.  One is to remove the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT field_5, record_meta_keywords
FROM cms_custom_database_1
WHERE field_5 > ''
ORDER BY field_5 DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The other is to combine the other data into a single column:

```
SELECT field_5, GROUP_CONCAT(record_meta_keywords) as record_meta_keywords
FROM cms_custom_database_1
WHERE field_5 > ''
GROUP BY field_5
ORDER BY field_5 DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` returns unique (i.e., distinct) occurrences. Take it out of your query statement.